# Facebook chatbot with node, express.js, ngrok and Dialogflow

Tags: node.js, webhooks, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger

I made this bot using express.js, node.js and ngrok. Its automatic answers are working fine, but this is happening only to my user, the user which created its facebook page, if other people message it, it won't respond.

I've already made it public, I have no idea what to do. What do I need to do so the bot respond to all users that message him?

I think its something about the Facebook configuration, because the bot is responding properly. How can I get help on this?

Comment: Did your facebook app go through the app review?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before a Facebook app goes to live, you have to make sure by the facebook authority, the app is using data in an approved manner.

From your app dashboard, you have to submit the application for review.

> Before you can switch your app to Live mode, we may need to make sure
>   that you will be using our products and data in an approved manner. To
>   achieve this goal, we require many apps to undergo App Review.

Without reviewing the application only the developers and the page associates can interact with the bot.

Check the [docs here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/).

Comment: So the app review takes about a week to approove an app...?  It was my first app, thanks for that information!

Comment: In my office, our app review took more than a week. It depends on the permissions you are required.